# Override sections.xml and remove action

Tags: magento2, overrides

i have a `Smile_Gdpr` module in vendor that have a `sections.xml`
This it's content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="smile_gdpr/consent/save">
       <section name="smile_gdpr_consents"/>
    </action>
    <action name="catalog/account/login">
       <section name="smile_gdpr_consents"/>
    </action>

    <action name="customer/account/logout">
       <section name="smile_gdpr_consents" />
    </action>
</config>
```

In my module insert an override of this file, into

> app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/etc/frontend/sections.xml

It's possible deleted some action (in my case `name="customer/account/logout")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there seems to be no possibility to get rid of one of the elements by creating a new sections.xml to delete a previous defined action...
The XSD file for sections.xml is located in

`module-customer/etc/sections.xsd`

And if you take a deeper look into that file, well, then you will see that there is not any other attribute or tag, that can be used, which you aren't using already inside your own `sections.xml`.

I would still see some possibilities to "remove" actions blocks , not from sections.xml, but at other points in the code. Here some examples:

- You could either change the virtual type, defined for processing the sections.xml, and f.e. providing a different name for the sections file
- Otherwise you could also create a plugin, so a specific action block won't be processed.
- You could just hide specific sections using css

(I didn't try any of these yet, but I guess that at least some of them would work)